# Order with nested associations using SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I get a error using `order` with nested associations.

I'd like to order each products in the `ProductTocategoryModel`.

When I remove the `ProductVariationModel` include, the order works, it seem's to be an issue when I have more than one include.

I have SequelizeJS 6.33.0 in my project.

**My code :**

```
ProductTocategoryModel.findAll({
  where: whereProductTocategory,
  offset,
  limit: NB_ITEM_PER_PAGES,
  include: [
    {
      model: ProductModel,
      where: whereProduct,
      include: [{
        model: ProductVariationModel,
        required: false
      }]
    },
    {
      model: ProductCategoryModel,
      where: {
        state: true
      }
    }
  ],
  order: [
    [ProductModel, 'position', 'ASC']
  ],
  group: ['productId']
})
```

**Error message :**

```
  Error
      at Query.run (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:52:25)
      at C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:12)
      at async Function.findAll (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1140:21) {
    name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
    parent: Error: Champ 'product.position' inconnu dans order clause
        at Packet.asError (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
        at Query.execute (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
        at Connection.handlePacket (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
        at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
        at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\****\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
        at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
        at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
        at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
        at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
      code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
      errno: 1054,
      sqlState: '42S22',
      sqlMessage: "Champ 'product.position' inconnu dans order clause",
```

**Edit #1 with associations :**

```
ProductVariation.associate = function(models) {
  models.ProductVariationModel.belongsTo(models.ProductModel, { foreignKey: 'productId' });
};

Product.associate = function(models) {
  models.ProductModel.belongsTo(models.ProductBrandModel, { foreignKey: 'brandId' });
  models.ProductModel.hasMany(models.ProductVariationModel, { foreignKey: 'productId' });
  models.ProductModel.hasMany(models.ProductTocategoryModel, { foreignKey: 'productId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
  models.ProductModel.hasMany(models.ProductPhotoModel, { foreignKey: 'productId' });
  models.ProductModel.hasMany(models.ProductStockModel, { foreignKey: 'productId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
};

ProductTocategory.associate = function(models) {
  models.ProductTocategoryModel.belongsTo(models.ProductModel, { foreignKey: 'productId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
  models.ProductTocategoryModel.belongsTo(models.ProductCategoryModel, { foreignKey: 'categoryId' });
};
```

Comment: Please show the associations between models

Comment: You can see my edit with associations.

Comment: I don't the association from `ProductTocategoryModel` to `ProductModel`

Comment: You can see my edit with this association.

Comment: Could you remove all unrelated included models, `where`, `offset`, `limit` and `group` options and try again? If it still fails please add the Sequelize query and the generated SQL to the post